# How can I distinguish between queued, played, and skipped podcast episodes?

Tags: podcasts.app

When a podcast that I follow releases a new episode, I often elect to skip listening to it if it doesn’t interest me. Prior to iOS 14.5, I did this by “deleting” the episode from my library. Now that option is gone.

I’ve discovered that I can still dequeue an episode by marking it is played, but that conflates played and unplayed episodes.

I’m happy to learn a new a paradigm for organizing podcasts but I can’t figure out what Apple wants me to do here.

Comment: Use a reasonable podcast catcher.  There are several.  Pocket Casts, Overcast, Castro... others.  But don't bother with the Apple one.

Comment: Do these non-Apple "podcast catchers" allow one to put podcasts on an iPod?  Doubtful I think.